How do I fix the error with UIViewControllerRepresentable?
I got the error on my visionOS app saying that my view doesn't conform to UIViewControllerRepresentable. I tried this code in another visionOS project and it works. Is there anything I can dp?
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import UIKit

struct PlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = AVPlayerViewController
    
    var url: String = "https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/bipbop_adv_example_hevc/master.m3u8"
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
//        controller.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
//        controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
        
        controller.player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: url)!)
        controller.player?.playImmediately(atRate: 1.0)
        
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
}

a prompt answer.....
